# Superset URL is being encoded after using WSO2 Authentication

Tags: wso2, apache-superset

I have Superset web where we are using WSO2 as authentication.

I also have separate web where we can redirect into superset dashboard with URL have query to Superset filters, which ofcourse have a quote, bracket, colon, etc.

If I haven't login into superset and click that URL, it will redirect me to [superset-url]/login?next=[superset-url-with-filters]

The issue is appearing here where [superset-url-with-filters] is being encoded by superset where quote `'` is becoming `%27` and link becomes invalid.

Any suggestion?